# React Native Inspect Element

Tags: react-native

In a previous example project I was able to type command+D in the simulator and the menu had an option to "Inspect Element" but for some reason my new project doesn't have that option.  How can I get the inspect element option in my current project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably caused by the version of react you use. The current stable version is 0.5.0. Inspect element only works in the 0.6.0rc (as of now). Check your package.json - it should contain "react-native": "^0.6.0-rc" (remember to update node modules:

```
npm update
```

See the release notes for details (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases)